502 Bad Gateway on https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.76.2|cms=WordPress
Getting this system error:

dh_c2ezex@xxxxxxx:~$ wget https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.76.2%7Ccms=WordPress
--2024-09-03 09:00:01--  https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.76.2%7Ccms=WordPress
Resolving civicrm.org (civicrm.org)... 45.79.135.8, 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe7b:2e21
Connecting to civicrm.org (civicrm.org)|45.79.135.8|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2024-09-03 09:01:55 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.

This error comes up every now and then. It is usually as a result of a temporary issue on the civicrm.org site and will no doubt be fixed in a short period.
It doesn't indicate anything wrong with your CiviCRM system so you can safely ignore this warning. Arguably this message shouldn't be shown with such severity. It's not a critical issue. It should be a warning or information message.

I've submitted a PR to reduce the severity here:  https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31112

Looks like this is resolved. No more error.
